# How can I browse a Folder with 150000 Files on Windows Vista/7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, windows-explorer

I recently used the Bulk Rename Utility to rename and move files from a bunch of subdirectories to a single spot. In the end, about 150000 files were moved. Now I want to browse them, but recall there being problems in the past.

I'm curious if there is a 3rd party utility that would allow me to peruse these files somehow?

Is the issue here a performance issue, a filesystem issue, or a hardware issue? I have a quad core machine with 8GB of RAM, but it seems hardware has little effect on improving the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use cmd.exe. It doesn't invoke any unnecessary file operations (which can slow down working with a huge amount of files).

Comment: +1 dir is quite efficient and is able to take advantage of accessing the file system at a 'lower level' than say Powershell.

Answer (score 2):

Explorer works for me pretty well even with such large amounts of files. Especially in the "Details" view you won'get thumbnails or other things that may slow things down too much.

Alternatively you could use an Orthodox File Manager such as [Far](http://farmanager.com).

Answer (score 1):

You could even use a script in Powershell or CMD or a scripting language to move the files into subdirectories to shrink the number (simply by 1st letter of name for example)